# Terraform forces AKS node pool replacement without any changes

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks

I have the following resource definition for additional node pools in my k8s cluster:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "extra" {
  for_each = var.node_pools

  kubernetes_cluster_id   = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.id
  name                    = each.key
  vm_size                 = each.value["vm_size"]
  node_count              = each.value["count"]
  node_labels             = each.value["labels"]
  vnet_subnet_id          = var.subnet.id
}
```

Here is the output from `terraform plan`:

```
Note: Objects have changed outside of Terraform

Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the last "terraform apply":

  # module.aks.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool.extra["general"] has been changed
  ~ resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "extra" {
      + availability_zones     = []
        id                     = "/subscriptions/3913c9fe-c571-4af9-bc9a-533202d41061/resourcegroups/amic-resources/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/amic-k8s-01/agentPools/general"
        name                   = "general"
      + node_taints            = []
      + tags                   = {}
        # (18 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

Unless you have made equivalent changes to your configuration, or ignored the relevant attributes using ignore_changes, the following plan may include actions to undo or respond to these changes.

──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.aks.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool.extra["general"] must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "extra" {
      - availability_zones     = [] -> null
      - enable_auto_scaling    = false -> null
      - enable_host_encryption = false -> null
      - enable_node_public_ip  = false -> null
      ~ id                     = "/subscriptions/3913c9fe-c571-4af9-bc9a-533202d41061/resourcegroups/amic-resources/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/amic-k8s-01/agentPools/general" -> (known after apply)
      ~ kubernetes_cluster_id  = "/subscriptions/3913c9fe-c571-4af9-bc9a-533202d41061/resourcegroups/amic-resources/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/amic-k8s-01" -> "/subscriptions/3913c9fe-c571-4af9-bc9a-533202d41061/resourceGroups/amic-resources/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/amic-k8s-01" # forces replacement
      - max_count              = 0 -> null
      ~ max_pods               = 30 -> (known after apply)
      - min_count              = 0 -> null
        name                   = "general"
      - node_taints            = [] -> null
      ~ orchestrator_version   = "1.20.7" -> (known after apply)
      ~ os_disk_size_gb        = 128 -> (known after apply)
      - tags                   = {} -> null
        # (9 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

As you can see, terraform tries to force replacement of my node pool because of a change in `kubernetes_cluster_id`, even though there is actually no change at all on this value.
I've been able to work around this by ignoring `kubernetes_cluster_id` changes in the `lifecycle` block, but I am still puzzled as to why terraform detects a change there.

So why does Terraform find a change in this case while there are none?

Comment: According to your plan output, the `kubernetes_cluster_id` is in fact changing, so Terraform is behaving correctly. Analyzing the plan further, it appears that `resourcegroups` is changing to `resourceGroups`, which sounds like the wrong `kubernetes_cluster_id` is READ at CREATE time, or some other related provider code issue. This sounds a lot like a bug you should file with the Azure provider.

Comment: Thanks a lot for catching that, I didn't realize there was actually a difference between the two strings. I will try to take the time to isolate a minimal test case to reproduce the issue and file the bug.

Comment: Removing a `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool` from the state and importing it again does not work. Removing both the node pool and the cluster, followed by importing the cluster (using capital R in the import-link), then the node pool, results in the same scenario: node-pool has a reference with lowercase R and forces replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this weird bug by introducing `lifecycle` block as follows:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "my-node-pool" {
  name = "mynodepool"
  kubernetes_cluster_id = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.id

  ...

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      kubernetes_cluster_id
    ]
  }
}
```

Not the cleanest way, but it works. Cluster Id should not be changed unless you recreate whole AKS Cluster, so it should be safe.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not proud, but I managed to work my way around this bug by using the "[replace](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/replace.html)" terraform string function.

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "extra" {
  [...]
  # Use this once the bug gets fixed in the provider, and delete the workaround.
  # kubernetes_cluster_id   = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.id 
  kubernetes_cluster_id   = replace(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.id, "resourceGroups", "resourcegroups")

  [...]
}
```

NOTE: I'm not replacing `/resourceGroups/` with `/resourcegroups/` because the `replace` function will default to consider this is a regex replacement, which might end up duplicating your forward slashes. (I didn't test this myself)

Comment: maybe you've solved this issue? I've got the same problem :(

Comment: The code in this answer is still being used in production in my case

Comment: ok my problem was that when using spot instances in node_pool, I need to set node_taint parameter, and the value can only be found in azure docs. And there's notes about that in terraform docs and they are very vague. I've ended up with this resource recreation.  So just setting node_taint to the value which terraform wants to change  solves the problem