# AKS k8s id "resourcegroup" change to "resourceGroup" and Terraform forces replacement of node_pool

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform

I have a Kubernetes cluster resource and an extra node pool resource associated to that cluster. Everytime I run `terraform plan`, the plan is to replace the node pool because the reference to the `kubernetes_cluster_id` supposedly changed but because `resourcegroups` changed to `resourceGroups` which is stupid. I don't understand why this happend though. Any ideas?

- Output of the plan:

```
~ kubernetes_cluster_id  = "/subscriptions/subscriptionId/resourcegroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/myCluster" -> "/subscriptions/subsciptionId/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/myCluster" # forces replacement
```

To be clearer, look at one right next to the other:

```
"/subscriptions/subscriptionId/resourcegroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/myCluster"
"/subscriptions/subscriptionId/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/myCluster"
```

- `main.tf`

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = "myCluster"
  resource_group_name = "myResourceGroup"
  ...
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "nodepool" {
  ...
  kubernetes_cluster_id = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.id
  ...
  depends_on = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks,]
}
```

Comment: What is the provider version?

Comment: @MarkoE I have tried from 2.79.0 up to the latest 2.82.0

Comment: And the latest is giving this same error? It sounds like a provider issue then. Have you checked maybe for open issues?

Comment: Yes, all the versions have the same behavior until the 2.79. So far I couldn't find any open issues on the official repo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terraform forces AKS node pool replacement without any changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67825862/terraform-forces-aks-node-pool-replacement-without-any-changes)